# ORMLite iterating over ForeignCollection throws the exception

Tags: java, android, collections, ormlite, foreign-collection

I try to iterate over `ForeignCollection<OrderItems>`. This works if `eager` set to `true` but the  lazy option still doesn't work.

Firstly, I make

```
OrderDataSource orderDS = new OrderDataSource(getAppContext());
ws.Order order = orderDS.convertToWS(mOrder,ws.Order.class);
orderDS.close();
```

Where `close()` close db connection and `convertToWS()` make iterating.

**part of `convertToWS()`:**

```
Iterator<OrderItem> itr = order.getOrderItems().iterator();

while (itr.hasNext())
{
    OrderItem orderItem = itr.next();
    ...
}
```

Method close is called after return from `convertToWS()`. I work with other objects in `convertToWS()` with any problem.

I try to use also `CloseableIterator` and close it in `finally` block, but without success. Expect of this, I don't close connection.

**Exception:**

```
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/my_app/databases/my_db (conn# 0) already closed
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1556)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1538)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:162)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:57)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:232)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createIterator(BaseDaoImpl.java:933)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.iterator(BaseDaoImpl.java:531)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.iterator(BaseDaoImpl.java:526)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.seperateIteratorThrow(LazyForeignCollection.java:74)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.iteratorThrow(LazyForeignCollection.java:60)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.closeableIterator(LazyForeignCollection.java:50)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.iterator(LazyForeignCollection.java:45)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.iterator(LazyForeignCollection.java:26)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at orders.OrderDataSource.convertToWS(OrderDataSource.java:409)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at fragments.OrderDetailFragment.sendOrder(OrderDetailFragment.java:419)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at fragments.OrderDetailFragment.doPositiveClick(OrderDetailFragment.java:347)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at ui.dialogfragments.AlertDialogFragment$1.onClick(AlertDialogFragment.java:54)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-17 02:21:43.094: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What happens when you make it eager fetch?

Comment: I made a mistake, eager works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the database open in order to iterate over the values since you are doing lazy queries, meaning you are fetching data from database the first time you access an object from the foreign collection.

So if you are extending the ORMLiteActivity then your database will stay open until you destroy that screen.

The main thing here is to keep the helper open while you are using the data.

Comment: I've updated my question, I've added details about iterating.

Comment: so when eager pulling you get all the data from the database. that connection is then released and you continue to work with objects in memory. when doing lazy loading you get only part of the data in memory and then continue to pull the rest as soon as you start accessing the data from the collection. As the exception states your database is closed when you try to iterate which is preventing pulling the rest of your data to memory. i wouldn't know why this happens in your case but my suggestions is to take a look at if possibly you are releasing the helper somehow before your iteration.